# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am using seq2seq model for Hindi to English text translation. I am not much familiar with keras or deep learning. While exploring seq2seq model I came across this example.

https://github.com/karimkhanp/Seq2Seq/blob/master/seq2seq/seq2seq.py

While running this program I get error

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape (1,10)
```

at line

```
temp[0:len(seq)] = seq
```

Error log -

```
[[4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000]]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seq2seq.py", line 92, in <module>
    Seq2seq.encode()
  File "seq2seq.py", line 58, in encode
    temp[0:len(seq)] = seq
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape (1,10)
```

Code:

```
def encode(self):
    #Encodes input sentence into fixed length vector
    #print("Enter sentence in hindi")
    inp = raw_input().decode("utf-8")
    tokens = inp.split()
    seq = []
    for token in tokens:
        if token in self.proproces.vocab_tar:
            seq.append(self.proproces.vocab_tar[token])
        else:
            token = "UNK"
            seq.append(self.proproces.vocab_tar[token])
    #seq = map(lambda x:self.proproces.vocab_hind[x], tokens)
    # Normalize seq to maxlen
    X = []
    X.append(seq)
    print(X)
    temp = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=self.maxlen)
    temp[0:len(seq)] = seq
    print(len(temp))
    temp = np.asarray(temp).reshape(128,)
    print(temp.shape)
    prob = model.predict_on_batch(temp)#, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
    translated = self.decode(prob)
    print("Tranlated is", translated)
```

Where is the dimention mismatch.

Original code had `temp = sequence.pad_sequences(X, maxlen=self.maxlen)` which I converted to `temp = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=self.maxlen)`

Comment: From the example:
`Seq2seq = train(10, 4000)`
Did you take care to make that initialization match the correct maxlen? I feel your problem should resolve itself if it is set to `Seq2seq = train(6, 4000)`

Comment: @Uvar: Thanks for your suggestion, but still same issue : (

Comment: Okay. New try. :) In example code; the line which gives you an error is commented out. (as well as the reshaped array)